# I'm having trouble choosing between Wilcoxon matched pairs test and McNemar test for a data set

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank, mcnemar-test

I have a data set on a large group of long-term stroke survivors. I need to determine whether there is a difference in ability (on a scale of 1-10) between their left and right arms. The ordinal data is heavily skewed towards scores of 9/10.

I'm wavering between the Wilcoxon matched pairs test or McNemar test, which should I use?

Thanks in advance,
Harry

Comment: McNemar's test is for dichotomous data, and its extension McNemar-Bowker is for polytomous nominal data. Neither of the two is for ordinal data.

Comment: @ttnphns thanks!